Python auto-py-to-exe .exe run only in the location where it is created and not in the other location
I have written a script for performing a regression test, which was functioning correctly in PyCharm and also when converted to an executable using auto-py-to-exe. However, after moving the executable to a different location, it fails to load all the test cases and only runs three. The issue now is that I cannot identify the problem because it's not possible to debug the code once it's in the executable form.
I attempted to import the logger module and executed the .exe to determine the precise issue location, but I am still unable to find an appropriate solution.
